# Difference in erasing an element from a vector and a vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    vector<int>p;
    p.push_back(30);
    p.push_back(60);
    p.push_back(20);

    p.erase(p.end());

    for(int i = 0; i < p.size(); ++i)
    cout<<p[i]<<" ";
}
```

The above code throws error as it is understood that p.end() point to null pointer.

While this code below is running fine and output is 30 60. Can anyone explain this?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define mp make_pair
int main() 
{
    vector<pair<int,int>>p;
    p.push_back(mp(30,2));
    p.push_back(mp(60,5));
    p.push_back(mp(20,7));

    p.erase(p.end());

    for(int i = 0; i < p.size(); ++i)
    cout<<p[i].first<<" ";
}
```

Comment: `p.erase(p.end());` is in both cases an access out of bounds, therefore it invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: This code is just horrible. You should stay away from sites preaching this nonsense.

Comment: Below code is running fine with output 30 60 !!

Comment: One possible effect of undefined behaviour is "running fine". Another one is "appearing to run fine, but crashing on a different system or compiler".

Comment: I have checked it on many online compilers but the output is same!!

Answer (score 3):

From [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) :

> The iterator pos must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the end() iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferencable) cannot be used as a value for pos.

So your code is invalid in both cases and invokes [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). This means anything can happen including crash, work, or whatever it wants.

Comment: My doubt is why the p.erase(p.end()) is not giving any error in case of vector of pairs and erasing the last element??

Comment: @vikaschoudhary Because the behaviour is *undefined*. Just like `int a[4]; a[6] = 10` is undefined. This might work, or fail, or crash or anything. It is not worth discussing what undefined behaviour might or might not do.

Answer (score 1):

> The above code throws error as it is understood that ...

That code is not guaranteed to "throw an error". Rather, the behaviour is undefined. Throwing an error is one possible behaviour. If it does throw an error, you can count yourself lucky as it might have been difficult to find your bug otherwise.

> ... as it is understood that p.end() point to null pointer.

No, `p.end()` does not "point to a null pointer". It points to the end of the vector, where *end of the vector* is defined as the position after the last element.

> While this code below is running fine and output is 30 60. Can anyone explain this?

"Running fine" and "output is 30 60" are possible behaviours when behaviour is undefined. Everything is a possible behaviour when it is undefined. But of course, there is no guarantee that it will run fine. As far as the language is concerned, the program could just as well not be running fine tomorrow.

> I have checked it on many online compilers but the output is same!!

Ouput being the same on many online compilers is also possible behaviour when behaviour is undefined. There is no guarantee that some compiler would behave differently, just as much as there is no guarantee for them behaving the same.

No matter how many compilers you try, it is impossible to verify that a program is correct simply by executing it and observing the output that you hoped for. The only way to prove a program correct, is to verify *all* pre-conditions and invariants imposed on the program are satisfied.

Comment: Please check the outputs of the program. It will work always and won't output garbage values.

Comment: I have checked it on many online compilers but the output is same!!

Comment: My doubt is why the p.erase(p.end()) is not giving any error in case of vector of pairs??

Comment: Because p.end() does not point to last element it points to position next to last element.

Comment: @vikaschoudhary but as I already said in my answer, that is not guaranteed to give any error. Why would you expect an error when there is no guarantee that there would be an error?